# Rails: has_many through association - did I get this right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through

I building a photo sharing web application using Rails 3.1. I just want to verify that I got the associations right.

Some context: A `User` has many `Share`. A `Share` has one `User` (i.e the "*sharer*"), one `Photo`and many `Receiver`. A `Receiver`is a arbitrary `User`.

The reason why I'm using a through association is simply because I want to store additional data for each receiver of the shared photo.

```ruby
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shares
end

class Receiver < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :share
  belongs_to :user
end

class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :receivers
  has_many :users, :through => :receivers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :receivers
  has_many :shares, :through => :receivers
end
```

Retreiving a `User` shared photos could then be performed using the `shares` class method?

```ruby
User.first.shares
# => [<#Share:0x000>, ...]
```

Retreiving a `User` received shares could then be performed using the `receivers` class method?

```ruby
User.first.receivers
# => [<#Receiver:0x000>, ...]
```

Did I get this right?

Comment: You were missing a `<` in `class Photo ActiveRecord::Base`, I added it for you.

Comment: And yes, your structure and code looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while ago, I didn't test this code, so play around with it and see if it actually is what you need, it may point you in the right direction though.

If yours work I don't see the point of changing it, this code is a bit more complex but you dont have a Receiver model, everything goes through the Share model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shares_links, :class_name => "Share", :foreign_key => :sharing_id, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :receiver_links, :class_name => "Share", :foreign_key => :shared_to_id, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :shares, :through => :shares_links
  has_many :receivers, :through => :receiver_links
end

class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sharing, :validate => true, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :sharing_id 
  belongs_to :shared_to, :validate => true, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :shared_to_id

  has_one :photo
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo
end

User.first.shares
User.first.receivers
User.first.receivers.first.photo
```

Comment: I may had understood the problem incorrectly :) if so, let me know to delete the answer :P

Comment: Not at all. I tried to accomplish something similar until I realized I wanted to store additional data about each share.